# HTML / JS- my radio button values are not storing correctly

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm trying to store my radio button values to my variable but it does not seem to pass through. And when i use checked It only displays that value and doesn't dynamically change.

I'm just trying to make a BMR calculator so i'm just making sure i am able to store values. I would prefer if i don't have to use JQuery if possible, thank you.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box
        }

        /* Set height of body and the document to 100% */
        body,
        html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        /* Style tab links */
        .tablink {
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
            float: left;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            font-size: 17px;
            width: 50%;
        }

        .tablink:hover {
            background-color: #777;
        }

        /* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */
        .tabcontent {
            color: white;
            display: none;
            padding: 100px 20px;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #Metric {
            background-color: royalblue;
        }

        #Imperial {
            background-color: mediumseagreen;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Metric', this, 'royalblue')" id="defaultOpen">Metric BMR Calculator</button>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Imperial', this, 'mediumseagreen')" id="defaultOpen">Imperial BMR Calculator</button>

    <div id="Metric" class="tabcontent">
        <form><br>
            <label>Sex </label>
            <select id="sex">
                <option value="M">Male</option>
                <option value="F">Female</option>
            </select><br><br>
            Age: <input type="text" id="Age" /><br><br>
            Your Height: <br>
            Feet: <input type="text" id="Feet" />
            Inches: <input type="text" id="Inches" /><br><br>
            Your Weight: <br>
            Stones: <input type="text" id="Stones" /> Pounds: <input type="text" id="Pounds"><br><br>


            <input type="radio"  id="id1" name="fit" value="30"  >
            <label for="id1" >I am sedentary (little or no excercise)</label><br>
            <input type="radio"  id="id2"name="fit" value="60" >
            <label for="id2" >I am lightly active (light excercise or sports 1-3 days per week)</label><br>
            <input type="radio"  id="id3" name="fit" value="100">
            <label for="id3">I am moderately active (moderate excercise or sports 3-5 days per week)</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="id4" name="fit" value="120">
            <label for="id4">I am very active (hard excercise or sports 6-7 days per week</label><br>
            <input type="radio"  id="id5" name="fit" value="140">
            <label for="id5">I am super active (very hard excercise or sports and a physical job or 2x training)</label><br><br>


            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="metricCalculation()" /><br>


        </form>

    </div>

    <div id="Imperial" class="tabcontent">

<!--
        <form><br>
            <label>Sex </label>
            <select id="sex">
                <option value="M">Male</option>
                <option value="F">Female</option>
            </select><br><br>
            Age: <input type="text" id="Age" name="Age" /><br><br>
            Your Height: <br>
            Feet: <input type="text" id="Feet" name="Feet" />
            Inches: <input type="text" id="Inches" name="Inches" /><br><br>
            Your Weight: <br>
            Stones: <input type="text" id="Stones" /> Pounds: <input type="text" id="Pounds"><br><br>


            <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="30" >
            <label for="age1">I am sedentary (little or no excercise)</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="60">
            <label for="age2">I am lightly active (light excercise or sports 1-3 days per week)</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="age3" name="age" value="100">
            <label for="age3">I am moderately active (moderate excercise or sports 3-5 days per week)</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="age3" name="age" value="100">
            <label for="age3">I am very active (hard excercise or sports 6-7 days per week</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="age3" name="age" value="100">
            <label for="age3">I am super active (very hard excercise or sports and a physical job or 2x training)</label><br><br>


            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="imperialCalculation()" /><br>
        </form>

     
        Test
-->

   

    </div>

    </body>

<script>
    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it


    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    
    
     function metricCalculation() {
        
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("Metric");
        theDiv.innerHTML += ("test<br>");
        var Age = document.getElementById("Age").value;
        var Sex = document.getElementById("sex").value;
        var Feet = document.getElementById("Feet").value;
        var Inches = document.getElementById("Inches").value;
        var Stones = document.getElementById("Stones").value;
        var Pounds = document.getElementById("Pounds").value;
        
//        var x = document.getElementById("test").value;
 //     var selectedOption = $("input:radio[name=fit].checked").val()
//          var gender = document.querySelector('input[name = Fit]:checked').value;
        
         var ele = document.getElementsByName('fit');
           
        

        theDiv.innerHTML += ("Your age is " + Age + "<br>");
        theDiv.innerHTML += ("Your Gender is " + Sex + "<br>" );
//        theDiv.innerHTML += ("Testing " + x + "<br>")
              theDiv.innerHTML += ("test<br>");
//           
            for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
                if(ele[i].checked)
                theDiv.innerHTML+= "Gender: "+ele[i].value;
            }
        
         theDiv.innerHTML += ("<br>");
//        theDiv.innerHtml += ("Your fitness level " + selectedOption + "<br>");

 
        
      
    }

   
    
     function imperialCalculation() {
        var Age = document.getElementById("Age").value;
        var LastName = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
        var Email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
        var Sex = document.getElementById("sex").value;
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML("<h1>Data Received</h1><br>");
        document.writeln("Form Completed<br><br>");
        document.writeln("The first name you entered is <b>" + FirstName + "</b><br>");
        document.writeln("The last name you entered is <b>" + LastName + "</b><br>");
        document.writeln("The email address is <b>" + Email + "</b><br>");
        document.writeln("Your sex is: " + Sex)

        document.getElementById('spanResult1').textContent = "hi";
        document.getElementById('spanResult').textContent = "cool";


    }
    

   



    function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
        document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
        elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
</script>
    
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('input[name="fit"]:checked').value;
```

Comment: thank you for your help but when i try this
my program doesn't display the value, and if i use checked in the input field, it doesn't update when i change options. Though at least it displays the value. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Oh! i just got it, the earlier innerHTML was eating the input for some reason. Thank you. I have to test some other things as well

Comment: will do, i also have another problem but i'm going to work on the base calculations first. thanks again.